# Python: override len

Tags: python

I have a question about the following method. `__len__()`. This is rudimentary but I am confused.

```
class PriorityQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = [None]

    def __len__(self):
        print('len is: ', len(self.heap) - 1)
        return len(self.heap) - 1
    def print_len(self):
        print(len(self.heap))

new = PriorityQueue()
```

If I use `len(new)`, then it produces 0, while calling the method `print_len()` produces 1.

Does this mean that a method inside a class does not use the `__len__` method(override `len()`) in the class and use python defined `len()` function?

Comment: `self.heap` is an instance of class `list()` and uses `__len__()` of that class. *The question is actually not as silly as it sounds, pls don't downvote it, unless it is a duplicate.*

Comment: I think you needed `print(len(self))`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Or just no `print_len` function. And instead only have `print(len(new))`

Comment: @cricket_007 - OP is already doing `len(new)` with the desired results. It's only in `print_len` that they're getting the length of `self.heap` instead of `self`.

Comment: Yes, `len(self.heap)` is greater than `len(self.heap) -1`. I'm unable to see what exactly confuses you.

Comment: I think I asked in a wrong way. I want to ask why calling `print_len()` does not use the user-defined method `__len__ ` and instead uses python-originally defined `__len__` method.

Comment: Because you call the `__len__` method of `self.heap`. To call the method you defined , call `len(self)`.

Comment: Thank you. I finally understand. I was stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking two different things. When you call

```
len(new)
```

Python really calls

```
type(new).__len__(new)
```

Inside your implementation of `__len__`, you check the length of `self.heap` and subtract `1`, giving you a length of `0`.

When you call

```
new.print_len()
```

you don't call `len(self)` but rather `len(self.heap)` (which is `1`). If you changed the implementation to call the former rather than the latter, you would get `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the len(new) calls __len__() . But I still don't understand why new.print_len() doesn't call __len__() (user-defined method) inside the class, and instead uses original __len__() method or len() function.

Comment: I didn't notice the difference you mentioned, and finally understand. Thank you.